# Dynamic Node path in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, process

I want to execute a js code in the node shell in a specific node version. The Script file is in the root of my project. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
$process = new Process(['/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/node', base_path('script.js')]);
$process->run();
```

and it's working. However that would probably only work on my computer, so i need to find the right path dynamically regardless of which environment the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function to get the Node.js path for a specific version:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
    
    function getNodePath(string $version) {
        $process = new Process(['nvm', 'which', $version]);
        try {
            $process->mustRun();
            $nodePath = trim($process->getOutput());
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
            // Handle the exception, for example: log an error or return a default path
            $nodePath = '/usr/bin/node'; // Fallback to the system default Node.js
        }
    
        return $nodePath;
    }
```

2. Update your code to use the **getNodePath** function to get the Node.js path for the required version:

```
    $nodePath = getNodePath('v14.17.5');
    $process = new Process([$nodePath, base_path('script.js')]);
    $process->run();
```

Comment: now i get this error: The command "'nvm' 'which' 'v14.17.5'" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Comment: See troubleshooting for nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-linux